# how can i display the result in value attribute of input from a separate php file?

Tags: php, html, forms

In this example, I will display my result in the value attribute of an HTML file, but without write the PHP script inside this attribute, I try to get access to this attribute from a separate PHP file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

  $result;
  if(isset($_POST['plus']))
  {
    @$result = $_POST['x'] + $_POST['y'];
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['produit']))
  {
    @$result = $_POST['x'] * $_POST['y'];
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['division']))
  {
    @$result = $_POST['x'] / $_POST['y'];
  }
  elseif(isset($_POST['moins']))
  {
    @$result = $_POST['x'] - $_POST['y'];
  }

 ?>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>learn send with php</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href = "send.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>

      <legend>calculatrice</legend>
      <input type= "text" name = "x"><br>
      <input type = "text" name = "y"><br>
      <input type = "text" name = "r" value = <?php
          if(isset($_POST['plus']) || isset($_POST['produit']) || isset($_POST['moins']) || isset($_POST['division']))
          {
            echo $result;
          }

       ?>>

      <button type = "submit" name = "plus">+</button>
      <button type = "submit" name = "moins">-</button>
      <button type = "submit" name = "produit">*</button>
      <button type = "submit" name = "division">/</button>
 </fieldset>

 </form>
```

I think the `$_POST` table use just the name attribute as a key of the table but my teacher told me that exists a method to accessing and modify in this attribute from a separate PHP file, but he forgot the exact way to do it.

Comment: If you want to send your form results to a different .php page set the `action` attribute of your form element to that .php file

Comment: yeah yeah i know that, i dont becaute do it because i dont know to get same result from arhoer php file.

Comment: You can read data, that came from another file/page form, with $_POST (like your codes) if your form has `action="thatFile.php"`. But to calculate something like `$result` and see it, you need to return it and get it in first file/page. This can be done with different ways, like (1) using JS Ajax, (2) redirect with a query and using $_GET, or (3) using a $_SESSION and then redirect to first one. For start make a copy of your file and then (1) remove PHP codes from the first one. (2) Add the name of the second one into the action=... (3) and then remove HTML codes from the second and test it.